# How correctly run evans (gRPC client)?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I have a `city.proto` file where I import a well-known third-party package called [gogoproto](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf). I created gRPC server and now I want to test it's rpc methods by [evans](https://github.com/ktr0731/evans) gRPC client.

I used such **command** but it raise an error:

```
evans proto/city.proto --host localhost --port 8000
```

**Error**:

> evans: failed to run REPL mode: failed to instantiate a new spec:
>   failed to instantiate the spec from proto files: proto: failed to
>   parse passed proto files: proto/city.proto:7:8: open github.com/gogo/p
>   rotobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto: The system cannot find the path
>   specified.

**city.proto**:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package proto;

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto";

option go_package = "./proto";

message City {
    uint64 id = 1 [
        json_name = "id",
        (gogoproto.jsontag) = "id"
    ];
    google.protobuf.Timestamp foundation_date = 2 [
        json_name = "foundation_date",
        (gogoproto.jsontag) = "foundation_date",
        (gogoproto.nullable) = false,
        (gogoproto.stdtime) = true
    ];
    google.protobuf.StringValue name = 3 [
        json_name = "name",
        (gogoproto.jsontag) = "name",
        (gogoproto.wktpointer) = true
    ];
    google.protobuf.StringValue country = 4 [
        json_name = "country",
        (gogoproto.jsontag) = "country",
        (gogoproto.wktpointer) = true
    ];
}

***
```

*go version*:

```
go version go1.12.9 windows/amd64
```

*protoc version*:

```
libprotoc 3.11.4
```

*evans version*:

```
0.9.0
```

In all probability, I am not correctly trying to start REPL mode. I assume that the command needs to specify the path to the directory where third-party proto files are located. I am confused. How start evans (gRPC client) correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run Evans correctly, it's required to specify the correct paths to search for imports by using `--path`.
It is almost similar to `--proto_path` in `protoc`.
For example, we assume that `github.com/gogo/protobuf` is located in `/path/to/github.com/gogo/protobuf`:

```
$ evans --path /path/to --path . proto/city.proto
$ evans --path /path/to --path . --proto proto/city.proto # Better
```

Note that `--path .` is also required to search `proto/city.proto`.

Well-known protos managed by Google such as `google/protobuf/wrappers.proto` and `google/protobuf/timestamp.proto` are loaded by default, but in other cases, we have to specify correct paths to use third-party protos.